# Allow friends to comment in a photo I'm tagged in

Tags: facebook, security, photos

My wife often takes photos of our child and uploads them to Facebook.  She tags me so my friends can see the photo as well.  However, my friends cannot like or comment on these photos.  When I do the same (upload a photo and tag my wife) her friends can like and comment on it.

On which account do I need to change security settings so my friends can like and comment photos I'm tagged in?

Answer (score 2):

The Help Center is a bit vague on your situation. According to the information there, your friends should be able to comment on the photos since you're tagged in them.

Therefore, take a look at the following settings in your accounts:

- Who can send you Facebook messages? (under How you connect?)
- Maximum Timeline Visibility (under How Tags Work - here you can limit the people who can see photos where you're tagged)
- privacy settings on the individual photos & albums (try Friends of Friends if nothing else works)

There used to be a setting called "Who can comment on my posts". It seems that it was dropped with the changes rolled out in 2011. It could that I lost it after migrating to the Timeline, so if you see it then that's what you need.

Comment: The most restrictive setting I have is "Who can post on your Wall? Friends".  Everything else is "Friends of Friends" or "Everyone".  I suspect it has something to do with "Who can comment on my posts", possibly on my wife's profile, but we can't change that setting any more...

Comment: @Hand-E-Food: Have you checked those settings on your wive's account?